# SARIMA forecast is just the previous year shifted

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am trying to forecast using the SARIMA model. I have used

```
auto.arima(ts,seasonal=T,trace=T)
```

but the prediction I'm getting is just the previous years values shifted up:
[image]

Clearly the 2020 values are just the 2019 values but raised. I'm not sure why this is happening? The model it fitted was SARIMA(5,1,4)(0,1,0)365, so

$(1-\sum_{i=1}^5 \theta_i B^i)(1-B)(1-B^{365})y_t = (1+\sum_{i=1}^4\phi_i B^i)\epsilon_t$

in backshift notation where $By_t = y_{t-1}$. I think I understand why the values are just the year before's, but not why they're so much higher.

Comment: the value at the last point is NOT being identified as PART OF A SEASONAL PULSE thus it is the point from future values are being launched from . tHE model you point to does not incorporate a SEASONAL PULSE indicator.

Comment: Maybe dups:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330928/time-series-prediction-shifted,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570404/timeseries-forecassting-load-forecasting-apparent-shift-in-actual-vs-predict,

Comment: Based on your model, these are not just the previous year's data, but it may well be that the difference to the previous year is very small, which happens often in ARIMA. The model you give at the end is not seasonal, you seem to be missing a couple of seasonal and nonseasonal differencings. Can we download your data anywhere? Finally, what data is this? The units on the y axis look intriguing, and you seem to have a two-year cycle in there (high in 2016/2018, low in 2017/2019), where does that come from?

Comment: @StephanKolassa apologies, I have updated the model in the question. I think I understand why the forecast looks like the previous year, I just don't understand why its so much higher. The data is not open source, but it is river flow daily. No idea why the 2 year cycles, no reason for it.

Comment: I don't see any annual seasonality in this plot.

Comment: @whuber perhaps not, unfortunately this is the data I've been given and have to treat as seasonal annually. I also agree it's not particularly strong. I just can't understand why the forecast is so elevated.

Comment: Try removing the annual seasonal term from your model.

Comment: @whuber that would help, but I more want to understand why this is happening than how to fix it. I'd like to know what in the model is causing the forecast to be so much higher than the rest of the data.